# Visual Studio Razor background highlighting not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have a weird problem and I just cant seem to make this work.

Razor background highlighting is not working for me:

[image]

But weirdly it does **works fine in PARTIAL VIEWS:**

[image]

I've spent hours Googling for a solution but haven't found one. Anyone experienced this? (I'm on Visual Studio 2017, had same problem with previous version too).

Tried tweaking the "Tools - Options - Fonts and colors - HTML Razor background" and other options - no luck.